# Concatenating a string to an iframe url causes it to not work. Any solutions?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, iframe

I'm trying to concatenate a string into the URL of an iframe but it doesn't work when I do this. Below is my function. Help is greatly appreciated.

```
function map(loc) {
  return (
    <div align="center">
      <iframe
        width="300"
        height="170"
        src={`https://maps.google.com/maps?q=獸醫+${loc}&hl=zh-TW&z=12&amp;output=embed`}
      ></iframe>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I tried other concatenating formats and it still didn't work. There aren't any error messages either.

Comment: Your problem may be from the chinese-like characters: 獸醫

Comment: Remove them and it should work

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you used a template literal backtick where you'd want to use a quotation mark.

Try:

```
src="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=獸醫+${loc}&hl=zh-TW&z=12&amp;output=embed"
```

Instead of:

```
src={`https://maps.google.com/maps?q=獸醫+${loc}&hl=zh-TW&z=12&amp;output=embed`}
```

The whole HTML code part is already a template literal and you can't really nest one template inside another;)

Full code just in case:

```
function map(loc) {
    return (
        `<div align="center">
            <iframe
                width="300"
                height="170"
                src="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=獸醫+${loc}&hl=zh-TW&z=12&amp;output=embed">
            </iframe>
        </div>`
    );
}
```